# RISC-V linker allows multiple definitions

Tags: c, linker, riscv

I am trying to replicate the behavior of the GNU linker with the `PROVIDE` keyword mentioned [here](https://www.acrc.bris.ac.uk/acrc/RedHat/rhel-ld-en-4/assignments.html#PROVIDE).

The compiler I'm using is `riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc`  version `11.1.0`.

I created a little project that is similar to the example provided in the documentation, I am however getting no `Multiple definition of...` error.

The project looks like this:

```
.
├── build.sh
├── link.ld
├── main.c
```

`main.c`

```
extern volatile int __var1;

int main()
{
    if (__var1)
        return 0;

    return -1;
}
```

`link.ld`

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(riscv)

MEMORY
{
    imem : ORIGIN = 0      LENGTH = 0x1000
    dmem : ORIGIN = 0x1000 LENGTH = 0x1000
}

ENTRY (_start)

SECTIONS
{
    .text : ALIGN(4) {
        *(.text)
        *(.text.*)
        *(.ctors)
        *(.dtors)
        *(.lit)
        *(.shdata)
    }  > imem

    .rodata : ALIGN(4) {
        *(.rodata);
        *(.srodata);
        *(.rodata.*)
        *(.srodata.*)
    } > dmem

    .data : ALIGN(4) {
        PROVIDE( __global_pointer$ = . );

        /* advance */
        . = . + 10;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __var1_loc = .;
        __var1 = .;

        *(.data);
        *(.sdata);
        *(.data.*)
        *(.sdata.*)
        _edata  =  .;
    } > dmem

    .bss : ALIGN(4) {
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
        *(.sbss)
        *(.sbss.*)
        *(.shbss)
        *(COMMON)
    } > dmem

  _end = .;
}
```

`build.sh`

```
if riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -fno-inline -Os main.c -T link.ld -o test_provide.elf; then
    riscv32-unknown-elf-objdump -d -M numeric test_provide.elf > test_provide.dis
    riscv32-unknown-elf-nm --defined-only test_provide.elf > test_provide.sym
fi
```

After executing `./build.sh`, I get the following addresses for the symbols:

```
00001014 D __var1
00001014 D __var1_loc
```

If I define `__var1` in `main.c`:

`main.c`

```
volatile int __var1;
```

The addresses stays:

```
00001014 D __var1
00001014 D __var1_loc
```

My question is: why didn't the linker fire an error although there are multiple definitions of `__var1` like the documentation says?

Can I rely on this behavior so that the linker always prefers the symbols defined in the linker script as `__SYM = VAL` and ignore the ones in the program?

Comment: There is no actual question in your post. You should include at least one sentence in interrogative form, marked with a question mark. It seems like you may be asking why the linker does not issue an error message because there are multiple definitions of `__var1`, one in the source code and one in the linker script. If so, you should explicitly ask that as your question. If that is your question, it seems like the behavior of `PROVIDE` is irrelevant, so it should be removed from your post. Just reduce the post to the essentials.

Comment: Thanks @EricPostpischil, I added questions.